# Will pre-oiled vegetables become soggy?

Tags: vegetables

I like to do small preparatory steps ahead, make cooking faster when I do have the time.  If I oil my vegetables and store in the fridge prior to roasting, will the oil penetrate the vegetable and make it soggy?

Comment: How long are you planning to store them in the fridge?

Comment: I don't know if vegetables absorb oil or not, but can't you just toss the vegetables with the oil when you put them in the oven ?

Comment: Marinating vegetables in oil-bearing marinades is not uncommon... and in some cases it even improves things when roasting - eg for onions, mushrooms, peppers to go on top of a pizza... marinating them in a mix that is heavy on olive oil makes things better!

Comment: I would refrigerate anywhere from 12hrs-3days in advance. And yes I could toss with oil at the time of cooking, but sometimes I think I will cook the veg right away and I don't get to it, or I realize the kids will distract me from making sure nothing burns.

Comment: Depends. Eggplant for example stores oil like a sponge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will definitely change some vegetables, specifically tender vegetables with large surface area (e.g. whole leaf ones). Have you ever tried making a complete salad including dressing, then storing the leftovers in the fridge for a day and having it limp the next day? That effect is due to oil.

The mechanism behind that has nothing to do with penetrating the vegetables or having the oil soak into them. It is just that it stops their perspiration, so they die off earlier than they should. (I know it is counterintuitive, but metabolically speaking, your raw vegetables are still alive in your fridge).

So I wouldn't describe the change as getting "soggy", especially because some kinds of vegetables won't change that much anyway. Especially those which are fruits or roots or tubers will stay mostly firm even when oiled. But e.g. spinach will be definitely different - whether you care for that difference or not is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like a **marinade** almost, it'll allow an even coating of the oil and shouldn't be an issue at all, maybe season it during prep too to add flavour. Obviously don't let it sit for too many days or it will go soggy and/or bad but **a day or two** should be just fine.